# Is it possible to have a request specific class available to the entire execution path?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

Consider the following ASP.NET Core project/class structure:

```
Request comes in   
  Middleware
    Controller [calls]
      BusinessLayer
        BusinessRules  
          HelperClasses
            DomainSpecificClass
                etc..
```

When a request comes in, I want to set some values in a middleware component and have them be available in a DomainSpecificClass - for that specific request.  I suppose, I could plumb these values through a combination of dependency injection and method parameters, but I was wondering whether there is a simpler way.

Something like:

```
// middleware class
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context) {
   // RequestContext is a made up class
   RequestContext.Referrer = context.Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString();
}

// DomainSpecificClass
private void DoStuff() {
   string referrer = RequestContext.Referrer;
}
```

Is this type of implementation possible in .NET Core?

Comment: Feels a bit like aspect oriented programming? (Like having a logger available to all classes?)

Comment: You can have scoped factory for types `DomainSpecificClass` need. When domain specific class ask for the type, factory will build it based on data of current request or provide already built instances.

Comment: @CaiusJard That's exactly like that.  Except the instance should be different for each request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a class which will provide required data from "current" request and register it in DI as "Scoped" - one instance per request.

```
public interface ICurrentRequest
{
    string Referrer();
}

public class CurrentRequest : ICurrentRequest
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;

    public CurrentRequest(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
    {
        _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
    }

    public string Referrer()
    {
        return _contextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString();
    }
}
```

With ASP.NET built-in DI container register implementation as "Scoped"

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor(); // Built-in extension method
services.AddScoped<ICurrentRequest, CurrentRequest>();
```

Consume it in the business layer

```
public class DomainSpecificClass
{
    private readonly ICurrentRequest _currentRequest;

    public DomainSpecificClass(ICurrentRequest currentRequest)
    {
        _currentRequest = currentRequest;
    }

    private void DoStuff() 
    {
        var referrer = _currentRequest.Referrer();
    }
}
```

`ICurrentRequest` abstraction could be declared in the Business layer, so any host of your application can implement it and business logic will not depend on "Http" abstractions.

Comment: How would I instantiate DomainSpecificClass?  It's currently instantiated from its caller in HelperClasses.

Comment: @AngryHacker, are you using Dependency Injection? If `DomainSpecificClass` get created manually than you can pass `ICurrentRequest` as constructor parameter to the class which instantiated by DI and than pass it to `DomainSpecificClass`

Comment: The dependency injection doesn't extend that far down the stack.  So essentially, I'd have to rely on DI to take it as far as it's implemented and then pass it manually.

Comment: Yeah DI make life easier in this case and probably in others as well, especially if you trying to keep business layer as "pure" c# code without infrastructure (web framework, database etc) dependencies.